# The first row is skipped when loading product by SKU

Tags: magento-1.9, product, catalog

This looks very simple but I have been pulling my hair on this for the last hour. I just want to load products data from a PHP array that looks like this:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'sku' => string '1HC220'
      'qty' => string '2'
  2 => 
    array
      'sku' => string '4LANT'
      'qty' => string '2'
```

The piece of code:

```
foreach ($products_arr as $row) :
    $sku        = trim($row['sku']);

    $product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStore($store_id)
        ->getCollection()
        ->joinField('qty',
            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
            'qty',
            'product_id = entity_id',
            '{{table}}.stock_id = 1',
            'left'
        )
        ->addFieldToFilter('sku', array('eq' => $sku))
        ->getFirstItem()
        ;
        (...)
endforeach;
```

But the first product in the array always returns NULL. If I var_dump `$products_arr` I have X products, but in the loop the first is never returned.

If I load the product individually, it is loading, but not as a first row of the array.

I know I am missing something, but can't figure out what.

Comment: How your `$products_arr` looks? Print the result here

Comment: I updated the code and added the array. Thank you @Priyank

Comment: @Priyank no still the same problem. SO strange...

Comment: What happens when you remove the ->joinField() from your collection? I ask because maybe the missing item is out of stock.

Comment: @seanbreeden no, it doesn't change. Whatever the first product is, it is the one that will result in NULL. In my exemple, if in the array I put the row with the SKU `'4LANT'` as the first in the array, this will be the one not loading. It really is the first row of the array that is 'missing'.

Answer (score 1):

Add per your code if I have this data it works fine for me

```
    $products_arr = [0 => ['sku' => 'Test40', 'qty' => 1], 1 => ['sku' => 'Test39', 'qty' => 1]];
    foreach ($products_arr as $data){
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStore(1)
            ->getCollection()
            ->joinField('qty',
                'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                'qty',
                'product_id = entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id = 1',
                'left'
            )
            ->addFieldToFilter('sku', array('eq' => $data['sku']))
            ->getFirstItem();
        echo "<pre>";print_r($product->getData());die;
    }
```

Make sure the store ID you are assigning has the following product.

Comment: It is still the same for me. The first product is NULL. What I didn't precise is that the array is built reading a CSV file line by line. A row of the CSV file consists of: SKU;QUANTITY;PRICE
But as you can see the array is well formed, yet I get the first product impossible de load.
I tell you, it is very strange. The dirty work around I ended up doing is adding an empty first row in the array that I don't load in the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

It was not Magento related at all.

When building the array from the CSV file, there was some hidden characters in the SKU that I escaped using `$field = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $row['sku']);`
I still don't get why those characters were added only in the first element of the array though.

Working now. Thank you guys